# Excel get multiple cell value as comma seperated array

Tags: excel

Here is my Table

```
Roll Result
1    Passed
2    Failed
3    Passed
4    Failed
5    Failed
```

on C1 cell how can I get all failed rolls as comma separated value? Expected result on C1 cell is- 2,4,5

Comment: for a vba approach see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706211/excel2011-vlookup-and-combine

Comment: or here for a UDF that mimics the TEXTJOIN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Office 365 Excel` has `TEXTJOIN()`, use it as an array formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:B6="Failed",A2:A6,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Earlier versions:

Put this in C2 and copy down the length of the data.  C2 will return your value after the whole column is filled with the formula:

```
=IF(B2="Failed",A2&IF(C3="","",",") &C3,C3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Any way on Office 2007?